How to Export audio file mixed by multitracks
I used multitracks of wavesurfer js to mix audio. I need to export the mixed audio to an mp3 or wav file
Sample:
https://wavesurfer.xyz/examples/?multitrack.js
After mixing, I need to export the mixed audio to an mp3 or wav file.
I tried to find in the documentation of multitracks, but couldn't find a function to export file.
